# How to check a condition on a join?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm trying to set up filtering for users on my Widget search. I want them to be able to click on a number of tags, and return only the results that have the correct tags applied.

The tables are set up as follows:

- Widget has many tags, through taggings
- Tag has many widgets, through taggings
- Taggings is a join table

In my controller, I am iterating over the widgets, and checking a condition on the tags join:

```
@widgets = Widget.all
@current_tags = [1,5,7,10,15] # Passed in from params
@current_tags.each do |t|
  @widgets = @widgets.joins(:tags).where("tags.id=?", t)
end
```

I only want widgets returned that have *all* of those tags.

This seems to work fine for one tag, but as soon as you click another, it creates a problem once you select more than one tag. Eg, this returns widget 1 as expected:

```
# Widget 1 is joined to tags 1,5,7,9
@current_tags = [5]
```

This returns no results, even though it should return widget 1:

```
# Widget 1 has tags 1,5,7,9
@current_tags = [5,7]
```

Am I doing something wrong in how I'm checking the joins between tags and widgets?

Answer (score 1):

You might be interested in the acts-as-taggable-on gem, but as to your question, it is a tough one! There is surely a powerful Rails idiom you could use, but here is a brute force method:

```
unless @current_tags.empty?
  # set initial state to widgets that match the first tag
  @widgets = @widgets.joins(:tags).where("tags.id=?", @current_tags.shift)
  @current_tags.each do |t|
    # then keep only widgets in initial state AND the next tag
    @widgets &= @widgets.joins(:tags).where("tags.id=?", t)
  end
end
```

Answer (score 1):

You'd rather change you query to this:

```
@current_tags = [1,5,7,10,15]
@widgets = Widget.joins(:tags).where("tags.id IN (?)", @current_tags)
```

It's looking for widget by user selected tag.

Comment: That gives you an OR, the poster asked for an AND: 
"I only want widgets returned that have all of those tags."

Answer (score 0):

If each widget is linked only 1 time to a tag, you can do something like that:

```rb
@widgets =
  Widget
    .select('widgets.id')
    .joins("INNER JOIN taggings ON taggings.widget_id = widgets.id")
    .where(tag_id: @current_tags)
    .group("widgets.id")
    .having("COUNT(*) = #{@current_tags.length}")
```

Another way to write this code:

```rb
widget_ids =
  Tagging
    .select(:widget_id)
    .where(tag_id: @current_tags)
    .group(:widget_id)
    .having("COUNT(*) = #{@current_tags.length}")

@widgets = Widget.where(id: widget_ids)
```

Answer (score 0):

A somewhat awkward way is making your loop chain `EXISTS` on top like so:

```
@widgets = Widget.all
@current_tags = [1,5,7,10,15]
@current_tags.each do |t|
  @widgets = @widgets.where(
    widget.taggings.where(tag_id: t).exists # << a bit of Arel for ya
  )
end
```

That should work **in theory**. In practice, I've seen code like this bug out with wrong parameter binding, i. e. Rails passing in *one* param for *two* place holders. You **might** be able to work around this by resorting to plain-SQL conditions like `.where('taggings.tag_id = ?', t)`.